# Facebook Showing Captcha to New TLD's When Sharing Something

Tags: facebook, captcha, sharing, tld

Recently I have changed my domain from old to new one. The old domain was .com domain and the new oneis .online domain. But the issue is when someone sharing a link from my website either its a single view post url or the home page what the url is. Facebook showing captcha to verify that the share one is human. This is very strange that new tlds is not working in facebook. And its very annoying for end users. Please help me to find the solution for this or share your issues if u hve the same issue. Because by this way facebook one will see this and will include supports for new TLD's.

Thank you so much

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is very strange that new tlds is not working in facebook

It *is* working - users just have to confirm that they indeed wanted to share the item, for now.

It is triggered by Facebook’s automated, machine-learning algorithms – nothing you can do about that. It will go away again by itself, once enough users have successfully confirmed the security checkpoint.

Comment: No this is not like that as you said. If you go and buy some standard domain name tlds like .com or .net and share a link from that domain it will never ask you for captcha. I have tested this and the issue is with new tld that facebook is not understanding and it thinks that it is not standard url

Comment: It might be that their algorithms gives those new TLDs a higher score to begin with. But still, this will go away once enough people solve the CAPTCHA and confirm that they indeed wanted to share this.

Comment: Thanks dear I will keep checking if the solution that you are saying is actually right then I will mark your answer :) Hope for the best thanks dear.